# Fetch data from api and put into constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constructor

I'm new to react native and I would like to fetch data from an API, so I can place those values in a constructor.

To know how to fetch data, I'm using this URL: (https://reactnative.dev/docs/network) (I'm also using this for testing the app)

Now I know how to put the data into a flatlist, but I want to put them in a constructor.

The reason for this, is because I want to check if some data in the json file has a certain value. I've been trying to do this for a week, but can't figure it out.

I know how to make a constructor, as I did some exercises with that. The constructor seems to be working with mock-data. But now I need the API data.

If anyone can help me with this, I would really be gratefull.

Comment: Usually, `constructor` is not a good place to put async logic like data-fetching. There should be a better way to achieve what you want, but can should provide some code snippets?

Comment: Well another way of doing it, is storing a the data into a variable. But I don't know how to do that either. The code I'm working with is in mostly the URL in the question(https://reactnative.dev/docs/network)

Comment: Oh I think I misread your question. But why do you want to put it in a constructor? I understand you need to check some data from your API, but does the result of that check have to live in a constructor, or it can live elsewhere?

Comment: Well the results of the api would preferably be inside table. Than an if else statement checks the value. In the example in URL it puts the value inside a FlatList, but I don't want the value to be inside there. Also I want a different class to check the value of that same table.

Comment: Still don't get what you are trying to achieve, you should rephrase the question so we can help you. What we need to understand here is what the result should be (what you hope to do by putting a value in a constructor) instead of your approach (how to put an async value inside a constructor) because that approach could be less than ideal if you are not familiar the mental model of React. Even better if you provide the specific snippets because reading code is always easier.

Comment: I can't really give you some snippet of code since it is still a work(mess) in progress. But what I want is to get the value out of the api(call that ValueRead). And then see if ValueRead equals a certain name. If ValueRead does equals a certain name a specific message will appear containing that name: "ValueRead has passed the test". Something like that.

Comment: I'm getting it. In that case, you want to control that specific message with a state, which can be set after the API call finishes and doesn't have anything to do with the constructor. You can do the followings:
1. Specify a state, something like `showTestPassedMessage: false`
2. After the API call, check ValueRead. If it equals a certain name, update `showTestPassedMessage` to true.
3. In the render function, render your message only if the `showTestPassedMessage` state is true.